# CSS3 box-shadow inset painful performance killer

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

After very hours debugging my app when I start first tests to deploy a Desktop executable with Awesomium (for Visual Studio 2010) I see a lot of render issues in webkit, since slow redraw and very slow IO when typing. At first I think it's because buffered Process API is unusable or had any issue on process IO buffering.

After that I start over a new project with Qt5 using Qt-Webkit (Again with Visual Studio 2010 SDK) and I had a worst performance.

Again after all this, I started another project from the scratch with Tide (Webkit/Linux) - and I was adding file by file and analyzing the app behavior.

Then I saw the application can ran with low CPU use and with 60 FPS on index.htm.

So after I put all JavaScript files from the original application in this new project he didn't change the frame rate. But when I put the CSS containing the Class below the application just started to consume 100% of CPU and the frame rate just dropped to ~10 FPS.

```
.overlay { 
    padding:30px 15px;
    background:#fff;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#F5F5F5, #CCCCCC);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.50),0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.30),0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.10) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 5px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.50),0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.30),0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.10) inset;
    box-shadow:0 5px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.50),0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.30),0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.10) inset;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7BWAW/1/

How can I rewrite this Class, More precisely, how can I rewrite this class without box-shadow inset?

I tried without no luck using a transparent PNG as a background, but do not by far the contours are similar.

As the project has many occurrences of the box-shadow inset in CSS, if anyone can give me a light I have to improve the layout that is already approved - removing the box-shadow inset.

Comment: CSS3 shadow, animations etc use hardware acceleration, if heavy animations are used along with shadows, your processor will scream the hell out, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7BWAW/2/) is a cropped version of your css, max what I can do, by maintaining your output, and I've made a [project](http://www.quratek.com/projects/neonize/) which uses shadows and heavy CSS3 animations, you can have a look and see your processor screaming

Comment: If you want a static shadow effect, consider using an image background.

Comment: @Asad the question is how use a image background to get a similar effect?

Comment: @AllysondePaula Use sliding door technique

Comment: @Mr.Alien the sliding door it's a nice when you have a fixed heigth and a fixed border radius.

Comment: @AllysondePaula Ya, so stick with the shadow or loosen up things a lil like use a radial gradient instead of inset shadow and use shadow around the element

Comment: @Mr.Alien I found another nice technique using CSS `border-image`

Comment: @AllysondePaula border image is fine but are you getting the desired effect?

Comment: @Mr.Alien compare http://jsfiddle.net/7BWAW/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/7BWAW/3/

Comment: @AllysondePaula Pretty close :D

Comment: `box-shadow` and a few other CSS3 features are known performance hogs in webkit http://mir.aculo.us/2010/06/04/making-an-ipad-html5-app-making-it-really-fast/ WebKit bugs have been raised ( https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22102 ) and fixed on some of these, but Awesomium doesn't seem to indicate webkit version in their release notes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After all I found another technique using border-image

```
.overlay { 
    border:30px solid transparent;
    -webkit-border-image:url(http://s22.postimg.org/5blh30bkd/overlay_border.png) 30 30 stretch; /* Safari 5 and older */
    -o-border-image:url(http://s22.postimg.org/5blh30bkd/overlay_border.png) 30 30 stretch; /* Opera */
    border-image:url(http://s22.postimg.org/5blh30bkd/overlay_border.png) 30 30 stretch;
}
```

**See the Fiddle solution:** http://jsfiddle.net/7BWAW/3/

But have limtations - I can't use border-radius and I need to use another DIV inside container Class .overlay, but solves the most part of my problem.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried and I received a message that I only can accept my own answer as correct tomorrow.

Comment: +1 Nice trick for making fluid size element's shadows without adding extra wrappers or using box-shadow (performance killer on mobile devices even without inset shadows). Although browser support isn't as good as other techniques.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before, the solution is to stop using shadow, and use small low sized image for making shadow around your box.

Answer (score -5):

you can write somthing like this using css and div :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:5px;heigth:5px"><img src="top-left-corner.png"></img></td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="width:5px;heigth:5px"><img src="top-right-corner.png"></img></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-image:url('body-left.png');background-repeat:repeat-y;"></td>
        <td>
            Contet of the box
        </td>
        <td style="background-image:url('body-left.png');background-repeat:repeat-y;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:5px;heigth:5px"><img src="bottom-left-corner.png"></img></td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="width:5px;heigth:5px"><img src="bottom-right-corner.png"></img></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables aren't supposed to be used for layout as they're not semantic to content when not displaying actual tabular data.